# How do I increase touch-pad senstivity using libinput?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, libinput

I am struggling to find optimal settings for a Thinkpad X1 Carbon (Gen 6) trackpad. I have tried synaptics, but the palm rejection didn't work well. Now I am trying to configure libinput.

The problem I have is that I have to press down very hard to initiate a two-finger scroll.

How can I increase the sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

This was something that was merged into the kernel sometime earlier last year (?) In short touchpad pressure depend on Device quirks specific to laptop models

So you would need to create a quirk similar to this

```
cat /etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks
[Touchpad pressure override]
MatchUdevType=touchpad
MatchName=*SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
MatchDMIModalias=dmi:*svnLENOVO:*:pvrThinkPadX230*
AttrPressureRange=10:8
```

For better reference and an actual guide, checkout this page https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-pressure-debugging.html#touchpad-pressure-hwdb

Comment: I could use some more guidance to get this working. For example, this command is not recognized on my Ubuntu installation `sudo libinput list-quirks /dev/input/event10`

Comment: What is the actual output of the command?

Comment: `libinput: list-quirks is not a libinput command or not installed. See 'libinput --help'`

Comment: Ah, replace it with `libinput qirks list /path/to/device` maybe?

Comment: That works `$ libinput quirks list /dev/input/event5

ModelSynapticsSerialTouchpad=1
AttrThumbPressureThreshold=100`

Comment: Great :D any other issues?

Comment: So now I can change the sensitivity numbers, but how do I know what the values means and what values to change?

Comment: You should give the **Debugging touchpad pressure ranges** in the article I linked, they explain it far better than I ever will be able to!

Comment: Sadly those docs do a poor job of explaining what is going on. For example, what do the numbers `10:8` mean?

Comment: From the man page `Set the logical touch pressure thresholds to down and up, respectively. When a touch exceeds the pressure in down it is considered logically down. If a touch is  logically  down  and goes below the pressure in up, it is considered logically up.` so 10 is the down thresold, and 8 is the up threshold. To me the numbers seem arbitrary, which is why you have to debug it. The man page is pretty sparse, but it seems to at least try to bridge the gap `man libinput-measure-touchpad-pressure`